# Join client pc to domain setup in azure vm over vnet

Tags: dns, active-directory, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I am having a very difficult time trying to connect my computer to a domain I setup in a azure VM. I have spent several days googling for answers and still unable to join. I am not that familiar with networking so hoping one of you can guide me in the right direction. I am using a point to site vpn. I can ping the AD server via IP but not by host name. When I try to join the domain I get this error:

> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.xxxx.local
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server
>     automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by
>     the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS
>     servers with the following IP addresses:
>
> 192.168.250.6 (IP of AD server).

ipconfig /all of client machine:

> ```
> Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.nj.net
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-5B-76-D0-FA-4D
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.119(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, August 28, 2018 4:33:23 PM
>    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, August 31, 2018 8:27:41 AM
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
>
> PPP adapter b2wise-vnet-weu:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : xxx-vnet-weu
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.252.2(Preferred)
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> ```

ipconfig /all of ad server

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : eypda44s54judkzq3onclf52qb.ax.internal.cloudapp.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0D-3A-44-50-8B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 30, 2018 12:32:05 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 6, 2154 7:29:42 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.250.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I tried making the client pc's dns have only the ip of the ad server and when I do that I cant access the internet or the network.

Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: Can you add the ad server ip in the alternate dns server of client? Is there any A record in xxxx.local zone of dns server?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT -  I added the ip of the ad server as an alternate dns server for the client with the same results. I looked at the dns and I do see an A record. Here is a screenshot of the dns settings. https://ibb.co/c6t6dU (thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probably reason is that P2S client has not the correct DNS server in the PPP adapter.

Once the network completely set up ( you point AD server IP address to the DNS server setting of the Azure virtual network). You can remove the VPN client, re-download the VPN client package on the portal, and re-install the VPN client. The DNS server for the client should display on the adaptor. Refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/562821/azure-point-to-site-vpn-but-no-dns).

My P2S client output is as below:
[image]

More details: [Azure Point 2 Site VPN: DNS config is wrong](http://masterandcmdr.com/azure-point-2-site-vpn-dns-config-is-wrong/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be like a DNS misconfiguration. I think that you should look at your VNet configuration.
This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview) might be helpful.
And also, I want to remind you that you need a Site-to-Site VPN to have a computer joined in domain on cloud.

But, also Azure offers more solutions to have a Domain Controller on Azure this called Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Managed Domain) which does not require VPN connection. 
[Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Managed Domain)](https://cloudopszone.com/azure-active-directory-domain-services-managed-domain/)